# Access to class field - thymeleaf, spring

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I print all values from List which is field in my class ?

Model

```
@Component
public class ResponseObject {

   public List<Integer> iWantIt = null;

   //GETTERS SETTERS
}
```

View

```
<div th:if="${T(com.example.test.model.ResponseObject).iWantIt } != null">
  <ul th:each="wanted : ${T(com.example.test.ResponseObject).iWantIt}">
    <li th:text="${wanted}"/>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I set this list with integers and this part is working for sure.

I get Exception evaluating SpringEL expression error

> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'iWantIt' cannot be found on object of type 'com.example.test.model.ResponseObject' - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: How are you sending that ResponseObject to the template?

Comment: the getter and setter must be public, also, as @dgarceran said, how are you passing the object to the template??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add ResponseObject in your model.

In your controller write this

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    ResponseObject responseObject
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("responseObject", new ResponseObject());
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Then access the model in thymeleaf as follows

```
<div th:if="${responseObject.iWantIt != null}">
  <ul th:each="wanted : ${responseObject.iWantIt}">
    <li th:text="${wanted}"/>
  </ul>
</div>
```